# Can't reorder column names using function

Tags: python-3.x

So I have a dataframe like this:

```
 df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,10,100],'B':[2,20,200],'C':[3,30,300]})
```

Then I created a function:

```
def reorder(df):
  col = ['B','A','C']
  df = df[col]
```

I then run the function to reorder the column in my dataframe; however, it doesn't seem to work this way when I use function to reorder the column, despite that I can do so if I don't use it as a function. The main reason why I use function to reorder my column is I will be using a clean_up() function with other line of codes to drop / rename a few columns.

Comment: add ```return df``` at the end of your function. So that it returns back the re-ordered DF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can return the changed dataframe from function

```
def reorder(df):
  col = ['B','A','C']
  df = df[col]
  return df

df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,10,100],'B':[2,20,200],'C':[3,30,300]})
df = reorder(df)
df

    B   A   C
0   2   1   3
1   20  10  30
2   200 100 300
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. A question, why do we need to include a return function here? As I can run other command lines just fine using function, but for this particular command line I can't do so.

Comment: Pandas documentation mentions this https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/overview.html.  Check the Mutability and copying of data section.                                                                                                                         
   If my answer solved your question , please also accept the answer